# Change scope to use sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have two ruby scope but they are not completely using activecord. How can I change it to use only activerecord or sql?

#### article.rb

```
class Article < Comfy::Cms::Page
  has_many :view_mappings
  has_many :favorite_mappings
  scope :top_by_number_of_favorites, -> { article.sort_by(&:favorite_score).take(10) }

  scope :top_by_number_of_views, -> { article.sort_by(&:view_score).take(10) }

  def favorite_score
    favorite_mappings.since(2.weeks.ago).count * 5
  end

  def view_score
    view_mappings.since(2.weeks.ago).count
  end
```

#### schema.rb

```
  create_table "view_mappings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.date     "date_viewed"
    t.string   "device_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "favorite_mappings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.string   "device_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.date     "date_liked"
  end
```

Comment: What? Scopes are an ActiveRecord feature. Ruby does not have "scopes".

Comment: `sort_by` is not and ActiveRecord method @max

Comment: Ah sorry missed that.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what are favorite_mappings and view_mappings? Associations?

Comment: @EugZol I've update the question with the schema for those two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some SQL magic:

```
  scope :top_by_number_of_favorites, -> {
    joins(:favorite_mappings).
    where("date_liked >= ?", 2.weeks.ago).
    group(:id).
    select("comfy_cms_pages.*, COUNT(*) AS favorite_score").
    order("favorite_score DESC").
    limit(10)
  }
```

First two lines – we join favorite_mappings to query result, selecting only ones which are 2 weeks old or newer. Then we group results by arcticle IDs, specifying that we want to select COUNT of likes. And then we just order them top to bottom, and taking first 10 records.

More on scopes:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

More on aggregate functions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html

Please note that you will have article['favorite_score'] for score. Also, all other fields of Article should be available to your code, as we specified `*` in list of fields to select.

Comment: Whoa, I'm sorry, I answered too fast, didn't pay proper attention that faviourite_scope is 'computed property' rather than database column. I will edit my answer.

Comment: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "articles"
LINE 1: SELECT  articles.id, SUM(*)*5 AS favorite_score FROM "comfy_...
                ^
: SELECT  articles.id, SUM(*)*5 AS favorite_score FROM "comfy_cms_pages" INNER JOIN "favorite_mappings" ON "favorite_mappings"."article_id" = "comfy_cms_pages"."id" WHERE "comfy_cms_pages"."is_published" = 't' AND (date_liked >= '2015-07-17 16:15:45.643007') GROUP BY "comfy_cms_pages"."id"  ORDER BY comfy_cms_pages.position, "comfy_cms_pages"."created_at" DESC, favorite_score DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: Oh well, change articles to comfy_cms_pages :) Will make edit for ya.

Comment: It throws a undefined method  sum error. I changed it to use count because thats what I really want anyway. And no need to multiply by 5 in this case so I was able to simplify some.   `scope :top_by_number_of_favorites, lambda {
    joins(:favorite_mappings)
      .where('date_liked >= ?', 2.weeks.ago)
      .group(:id)
      .select('comfy_cms_pages.id, COUNT(*) AS favorite_count')
      .order('favorite_count DESC')
      .limit(10)
  }`

Comment: I'm not longer getting an error, `missing attribute: slug` in the model but now the haml view throws an error on `- @top_favorited_articles.each do |article|`

Comment: Edited my answer to include all attributes of Article (`comfy_cms_pages.*` instead of `.id`). I bet error is related to that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Article < Comfy::Cms::Page
  has_many :favorite_mappings
  has_many :view_mappings

  def self.top_by_number_of_favorites(since = 2.weeks.ago, amount = 10)
    with_favorite_score
      .where('date_liked >= ?', since)
      .order('favorite_score DESC')
      .limit(amount)
  end

  def self.top_by_number_of_views(since = 2.weeks.ago, amount = 10)
    with_view_score
      .where('date_viewed >= ?', since)
      .order('view_score DESC')
      .limit(amount)
  end

  def self.with_favorite_score
    joins(:favorite_mappings)
      .select('articles.*, COUNT(favorite_mappings.id) AS favorite_score')
      .group(:id)
  end

  def self.with_view_score
    joins(:view_mappings)
      .select('articles.*, COUNT(view_mappings.id) AS view_score')
      .group(:id)
  end
end
```

I also made it so you can change the lookback date, so instead of 2 weeks, you could get the top articles from the last month, year, or since any arbitrary date. The limit is now changeable as well, so you can get the top 20, 50, 100, etc. You can also access the favorite_score/view_score like this `@articles.top_by_number_of_views.first.view_score`.

Comment: I doubt that will work, because 'includes' doesn't insert JOIN into your query. It actually makes two queries: first to fetch IDs of parent record (on which you call #include), and second one to fetch associations (and adding "WHERE id IN (...)" to that query).

Comment: Throws an error `undefined method `includes' for #<Article:0x007f9409a864a8>`

Comment: Thanks EugZol, you were right about using `joins` rather than `includes`. I thought I had used `includes` in a case like this before, but I must have been mistaken. Antarr, check out my updates, they should work now.

Comment: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "favorite_mappings.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  *, COUNT(favorite_mappings.id) * 5 AS favorite_score...`
                ^

Comment: `: SELECT  *, COUNT(favorite_mappings.id) * 5 AS favorite_score FROM "comfy_cms_pages" INNER JOIN "favorite_mappings" ON "favorite_mappings"."article_id" = "comfy_cms_pages"."id" WHERE "comfy_cms_pages"."is_published" = 't' AND (date_liked >= '2015-07-17 16:56:17.838166') GROUP BY "comfy_cms_pages"."id"  ORDER BY comfy_cms_pages.position, "comfy_cms_pages"."created_at" DESC, favorite_score DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: How are you using the scope? Because in my test app, when I do something like `Article.top_by_number_of_views` it works perfectly.

Comment: @top_favorited_articles = Article.top_by_number_of_favorites

Comment: Maybe it is an issue with PostgreSQL vs SQLite. I will investigate and see what I find.

Comment: Check out the code in my updated answer, I got that to work using PostgreSQL.